Oracle Linux 8 server won't update because of missing files
I seem to have gotten my server into a wonky state. When doing a "dnf update" I get a bunch of failures like so:
Error unpacking rpm package libgomp-8.5.0-20.0.2.el8.x86_64
  Upgrading        : gcc-8.5.0-20.0.2.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                    37/108 
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/lib/.build-id/37/95071e4cb99f9b527940e045e021c408403059;65c5325e: cpio: (error 0x2)
error: libgomp-8.5.0-20.0.2.el8.x86_64: install failed
error: lsetfilecon: (-1 cc;65c5325e, system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0) No such file or directory
error: Plugin selinux: hook fsm_file_prepare failed

The specified file (in this example /usr/lib/.build-id/37/95071e4cb99f9b527940e045e021c408403059;65c5325) does indeed not exist. The missing file isn't always in /usr/lib/.build-id but the majority of them are. I have 108 packages that won't install now. I do updates on this server every three months or when a serious security patch comes out so I know I wasn't having this problem not so long in the past.
The system is OracleLinux 8.9 and it was installed with the DISA STIGs security profile option in the installer. Please let me know what other information you need so that I can get this system updating once again.

This issue was caused by a bad update Oracle made to the package rpm-plugin-selinux which eliminated some selinux labels necessary for various packages to operate when selinux is enabled. They quickly fixed the bad package but if you had automatic security updates turned on, your system will have updated itself into a state where it can't install the fix. To get out of this state, downgrade the package and then update like so:
rpm -e --nodeps rpm-plugin-selinux
dnf downgrade rpm
dnf install rpm-plugin-selinux-4.14.3-26.0.1.el8.x86_64
dnf update --exclude=*rpm*
dnf update

